# Burninate 'legal'

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags

Seeing [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/398995/9278) revealed that we have a [legal](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag. As legality is and always will be a local matter there can be no legitimate use for such a tag.

Comment: Agree. There's a lot of them there, so we'll have to change them over a few hours so they dont flood the front page

Comment: In fact, most of them are closed anyway

Comment: ***STAB STAB STAB***

Comment: That, and we likely have very few lawyers here anyway. Dispensing legal advice can be a Very Bad Thing.

Comment: And even if we were all lawyers, such advise would still be too localised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [legal](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag is no more.